How to set the background color on current date and absent date in the Custom Calender view in android
Good evening everyone, I tried more but still now can't find out the method to set the background Color of the particular date in the custom Calender view .
Current date becomes green Color and absent day become red like that.
If any one suggest to resolve my issues!!
